# RangecopyFormat (only) from one spreadsheet to another with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been searching for days to accomplish this without success. I have multiple users with different spreadsheets that look the same but have different ID's and security.  If I make a change in format to my base sheet I need to pull the new formats from there and distribute to all users sheets so I am consistent across the board.

*Do not want to copy values
*Do not want to copy sheet to 'Copied Sheet' and then delete and rename sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample with "[copyFormatToRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))":

```
var config = {
  // range to modify
  range: "A1:C3",
  // list of spreadsheets/sheets to modify
  spreadSheets: [
    {
      // from spreadsheets url https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXX/edit#gid=YYY
      spreadSheetId: 'XXX',
      sheetId: YYY // always "0" at the creation of the first (spread)sheet
    }
  ]
};

// update spreadsheets
function updateSpreadSheets() {
  for (var i = 0, j = config.spreadSheets.length; i < j; i++) {

    // get the spreadsheet to modify
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(config.spreadSheets[i].spreadSheetId);
    // get the sheet to modify
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets().filter(function(s) { return s.getSheetId() === config.spreadSheets[i].sheetId; })[0];

    // copy from the original sheet into the spreadsheet to modify
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().copyTo(spreadsheet);

    // get the new tmp sheet
    var sheetTmp = spreadsheet.getSheets()[spreadsheet.getNumSheets()-1];
    // get the range from the tmp sheet
    var sheetTmpRange = sheetTmp.getRange(config.range);

    // copy the format from the tmp sheet to the sheet to modify
    sheetTmpRange.copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    // remove the tmp sheet
    spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheetTmp);
  }
}
```

Plus, if you need these functions to retrieve ids:

```
// get spreadsheet id
function getSpreadSheetId() {
 Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
}

// get spreadsheet sheet id
function getSheetId() {
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Possible Solution:

You can use the Sheets API to get the format from one Spreadsheet and update another Spreadsheet.

#### Flow:

- Use `Spreadsheets.get` to get source format
- Use `updateCells` batchUpdate request to update another spreadsheet with source format

#### Sample Script:

```
function copyFormatFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet() {
  var sourceSsId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(),
    destSsId = '##destSpreadsheetIdHere##',
    sourceRng = 'Sheet1!A1:B4',
    destRng = {
      //Must be of same dimensions as sourceRng
      //Represents Sheet1!B1:C4
      sheetId: 123456789, //use 9 digit GridId
      startRowIndex: 0,
      endRowIndex: 4, //end exclusive
      startColumnIndex: 1,
      endColumnIndex: 3,
    };

  /*Get Format of Source Spreadsheet*/
  var rowData = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(sourceSsId, {
    ranges: sourceRng,
    fields: 'sheets.data.rowData.values.userEnteredFormat',
  }).sheets[0].data[0].rowData;

  /*Copy Format to Destination Spreadsheet*/
  var request = {
    requests: [
      {
        updateCells: {
          rows: rowData,
          fields: 'userEnteredFormat',
          range: destRng,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request, destSsId);
}
```

#### References:

- [Sheets API  Basic Concepts](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)
- [Enabling Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [`Spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [`UpdateCells Request`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest)

Answer (score 1):

use `getBackgrounds()` and `setBackgrounds()` of the Range Object to first copy of the cell background and then set it to the necessary range in any spreadsheet.
Similarly use `getFontColors()` and `setFontColors()` for changing the font colors. You'll find these and other similar funtions on this page.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontsizesize